# oracle 11g r2 - deploying dbmsclr.plb as sysdba after ODAC installation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odac

I just finished installing ODTwithODAC112012 on my system. Now I am trying to deploy dbmsclr.plb

But I am getting the error SP2-024 nothing to change.

Here is the command window:-

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog  

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Aug 14 22:59:39 2012  

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.  

SQL> connect sys/Bel29072012 as SYSDBA  
Connected.  
SQL> C:\app\thoshiba\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\dbmsclr.plb  
SP2-0024: Nothing to change.  
SQL> select count(*) from all_objects where object_name='DBMS_CLR';  

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(*) from all_objects where object_name='DBMS_CLR' AND owner='SYS';  

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Please let me know how to overcome this issue.

Comment: I'd recommend to set sql_trace (or event 10046) to see what the actual statement is where the plb file fails.

Comment: Thank you steve, now i am getting following error
SP2-0023: String not found.

Comment: I was missing the @ symbol at the beginning of the command line :- SQL> @C:\app\thoshiba\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\dbmsclr.plb worked fine !

Comment: Thanks @sujimon. I solved the error following your comment. Adding your comment as ans for future reader.

Answer (score 0):

To gedrid of "SP2-024 nothing to change" error Need to add **@** before running the script like

```
SQL> @C:\app\thoshiba\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\dbmsclr.plb
```